# Specifying data type in Pandas csv reader

Tags: python, pandas

I am just getting started with Pandas and I am reading in a csv file using the [`read_csv()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) method. The difficulty I am having is preventing pandas from converting my telephone numbers to large numbers, instead of keeping them as strings. I defined a converter which just left the numbers alone, but then they still converted to numbers. When I changed my converter to prepend a 'z' to the phone numbers, then they stayed strings. Is there some way to keep them strings without modifying the values of the fields?

Comment: Please show us your code

Comment: @Gardner: have you considered accepting an answer?

Answer (score 98):

Since Pandas 0.11.0 you can use dtype argument to explicitly specify data type for each column:

```
d = pandas.read_csv('foo.csv', dtype={'BAR': 'S10'})
```

Comment: Note that this is not available (yet, hopefully) for some other input functions, like `pandas.read_fwf()`

Comment: I revisited the topic and support for `dtype` has been already added to the `pandas.read_fwf` :)

Comment: This method doesn't work for large datasets is there any other way to read a csv and only particular columns.

Comment: This doesn't work when the input is a bytes io object, I get error `EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file`. Any way to solve this?

Answer (score 20):

It looks like you can't avoid pandas from trying to convert numeric/boolean values in the CSV file. Take a look at the source code of pandas for the IO parsers, in particular functions `_convert_to_ndarrays`, and `_convert_types`.
https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/parsers.py

You can always assign the type you want *after* you have read the file:

```
df.phone = df.phone.astype(str)
```

Comment: Thanks @lbolla, this helped in one of my bugfix, where a float value was read as string since another column was string, and later causing issues in aggregation functions. I had to do df['col'] = df['col'].astype(float64)

Comment: say I have a column of ids (which is all int) that I'd like to use as string, but by some condition pandas will read them as float, 1->1.0, 2->2.0, then without convert it back to int first, it will be converted to '1.0', '2.0' which is not desirable. that's why I just want pandas to read it as string.

Comment: This is not the answer. Your solution doesn't solve tproblems as memory error on big files.

Comment: this won't solve issues where there are leading zeros that get lost