# Writing values of a .csv file into dataframe as they are

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have 2 CSV files with similar data as below:

File 1:

```
1234    | Hamlet
2345    | Shakespeare
234     | Juliet
hello   | Romeo
hi      | 12334
```

File 2:

```
1234    | Achilles
2233    | Odysses
22334   | Hector
```

But when I load these into dataframes, all the values get loaded as string as below:

File 1:

```
'1234'    | 'Hamlet'
'2345'    | 'Shakespeare'
'234'     | 'Juliet'
'hello'   | 'Romeo'
'hi'      | '12334'
```

File 2:

```
'1234'    | 'Achilles'
'2233'    | 'Odysses'
'22334'   | 'Hector'
```

Is there a way where I can load int values as int and float as float and string as str?

Note: We don't know what data will be present in the csv files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specifying data type in Pandas csv reader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10591000/specifying-data-type-in-pandas-csv-reader)

Comment: @Shri you mean you want mixed data types in the same column?

Comment: @Adam.Er8 Yeah! Exactly :D

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment due to low karma, but check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47542745/combining-mixed-data-types-in-pandas-column?rq=1) out. It may help you.

```
df['col1'] = pd.to_numeric(df['col1'], errors='coerce')
```

I don't know what the name of the column was so I just took it as col1.